# "column ... does not exist" error when calling an SQL procedure (new in PostgreSQL 11)

Tags: postgresql, parameter, postgresql-11, sql-procedure

Using PostgreSQL 11 Beta 2, a very simple `trading_holiday` table is created in the `config` schema:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS config.trading_holiday;
CREATE TABLE config.trading_holiday
(
  id smallint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  holiday_date DATE,
  name CHARACTER VARYING(80)
);
ALTER TABLE config.trading_holiday
  ADD CONSTRAINT trading_holiday_pk
  PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Then a very simple stored procedure, `config.sp_add_holiday` is created to add holidays to the table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE config.sp_add_holiday(holiday_date DATE, 
                                                  name CHARACTER VARYING(80))
AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO config.trading_holiday(holiday_date,name)
    VALUES(sp_add_holiday.holiday_date,sp_add_holiday.name);
END
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Then a simple call is made to add the first holiday:

```
CALL config.sp_add_holiday(holiday_date='2018-01-01',name='New Years Day');
```

And I get the following error message:

```
[2018-08-07 11:56:18] [42703] ERROR: column "holiday_date" does not exist
[2018-08-07 11:56:18] Position: 21
```

Doing a manual insert, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO config.trading_holiday(holiday_date,name)
  VALUES('2018-01-01','New Years Day');
```

Works successfully:

```
[2018-08-07 12:04:01] 1 row affected in 2 ms
```

Despite being new to the PostgeSQL 11 SQL procedure functionality (who isn't?), this seems like such a simple proc. What in the world am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the parameter assignment **in the call**. To **fix**:

```
CALL config.sp_add_holiday(holiday_date => '2018-01-01', name => 'New Years Day');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=00202d6efed9268bb7b45f029bda5fb9)*

#### Explanation

Parameter notation is the same for functions and procedures (new in Postgres 11). [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/sql-call.html)

> See [Section 4.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html) for the full details on **function and procedure call syntax, including use of named parameters**.

**Bold** emphasis mine.

You have been using **`=`** by mistake. That's the plain old ["equal" operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html), forming a **boolean expression**. Obviously not what you intended. The expression is evaluated, Postgres looks for a column named "holiday_date" in the calling SQL context and cannot find it. Hence the error message:

> ```
> ERROR: column "holiday_date" does not exist
> ```

Only **`=>`** (SQL-standard notation ) or **`:=`** are valid for parameter assignment in the call. [Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CALLING-FUNCS-NAMED) Related:

- [Functions with variable number of input parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16782199/functions-with-variable-number-of-input-parameters/16789179#16789179)

There is a **history of misunderstandings** around the use of ...

- ... the operators **`=`** and **`:=`** in **plpgsql code**.
- ... the use of **`=`** as short syntax for `DEFAULT` in **`CREATE FUNCTION`** and now also **`CREATE PROCEDURE`** statements.
- ... the assignment notation **`=>`** and **`:=`** in **function calls**.

Further reading:

- [The forgotten assignment operator “=” and the commonplace “:=”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace/22001209#22001209)

Comment: I avoided the term "stored procedure" because it has been abused a lot to talk about *functions* in the past. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118418/when-to-use-stored-procedure-user-defined-function/118419#118419