# How to use variables in procedure (not function)?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, functions, plpgsql, sql-procedure

As I understand, in Postgres, procedures are for manipulating data and functions are for reading data. I would like to:

1. declare a variable
2. select a value into a variable
3. insert the variable into another table
4. do this in a transaction
5. do this in a stored procedure
6. roll back if necessary

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_variable()
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    BEGIN;
        DECLARE some_id INTEGER;
        SELECT nextval('some_sequence') INTO some_id;
        INSERT INTO some_table (some_column) VALUES (some_id);
    END;
$$;
```

The above is not working out for me. When I search for solutions, there's so many different variables involving functions, `$$`, declaration, thing not returning anything; can't seem to find a simple example; I just need a clear example of the syntax.

Comment: Functions can manipulate data just as well - they just can't control transactions. What exactly "isn't working" for you? What is the error you get?

Comment: When I run the above, I can't seem to declare the variable `some_id`. `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTEGER"`.

Comment: [As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-structure.html) the `declare` section must come before the first `begin` block

Comment: `BEGIN` and `BEGIN;` are two different things.  You need at least `DECLARE ...; BEGIN -- without semicolon! ... END; block, just as @a_horse_with_no_name said.  Also, a function call is always wrapped in a transaction, so you don't necessarily have to deal with it yourself in a procedure.

Comment: `procedures are for manipulating data and functions are for reading data`. Whoever told you this, may be an expert on flying saucers, but certainly not on Postgres.

Comment: @dezso: All true - in plpgsql. The OP has `LANGUAGE SQL` ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter you are right, but the body of the procedure suggests otherwise.  In an SQL procedure you cannot declare a variable (other than the attributes) anyway, just as you hinted in your answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[**SQL** functions or procedures (`LANGUAGE sql`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) do not have a `DECLARE` section - nor `BEGIN` / `END`. These are keywords for the [block structure of the procedural language PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) - in functions and procedures alike. (Maybe other PLs, too.)

[Like dezso commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221637/postgres-variable-in-procedure-not-function/221678#comment434982_221637), do not confuse PL/pgSQL [`BEGIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) (starting a block) with SQL [`BEGIN;`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-begin.html) (starting a transaction). *Neither* is allowed in an SQL *function*. The latter is also not allowed in an SQL procedure. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html)

> In procedures invoked by the `CALL` command as well as in anonymous
> code blocks (`DO` command), it is possible to end transactions using
> the commands `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK`. A new transaction is started
> automatically after a transaction is ended using these commands, so
> there is no separate `START TRANSACTION` command. (Note that `BEGIN`
> and `END` have different meanings in PL/pgSQL.)

To use **variables**, you need **`LANGUAGE plpgsql`** (or one of the other PLs). To give a clear example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_variable()
 LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$
DECLARE
   _some_id int;
BEGIN
   SELECT nextval('some_sequence') INTO _some_id;
   INSERT INTO some_table (some_column) VALUES (_some_id);
END
$$;
```

The exactly same body would work for a function as well.

Comment: Your comment about transactions, does a plpgsql procedure use transactions? Is a code block a transaction? Or do you have to use SQL procedures to use transactions?

Comment: @AWEInCA: Understand the terms "transaction", "code block", "procedure", and "function" to get a grip on this. There are links to the manual in my answer. Most importantly, a `PROCEDURE` can commit the current transaction and start a new one. Consequently, it cannot be nested in an outer transaction if it does. Related answers (with links to yet more): https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/290944/3684, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/118419/3684