# PostgreSQL: Issue Declaring Variables in Query

Tags: postgresql, query, variable

I'm trying to declare a variable for later use in a PostgreSQL query. I've done this often in TSQL, but I wasn't sure about the syntax.

The stuff I've seen online all points to something like this:

```
declare timestamp_utc timestamp := current_timestamp;
select start_date;
```

when I run the above query, I get an error message:

[image: ERROR: syntax error at or near "timestamp"]

I'm sure this is simple, but I just can't find the answer online. Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no variables in plain SQL.
You can use ["customized options"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html) as limited workaround. See:

- [Declaring variable for a whole script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213919/declaring-variable-for-a-whole-script/213921#213921)

Server-side procedural languages like [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) have variables. You can use   `DECLARE` in a code block - in functions, procedures and in anonymous code blocks executed with the [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) command. PL/pgSQL is the default PL for the latter. See:

- [How to use variables in procedure (not function)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221637/how-to-use-variables-in-procedure-not-function/221678#221678)

Or you can set variables in the client, like the default command-line terminal [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html). See:

- [PSQL passing external variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71073635/939860)
- [How to pass variable to PL/pgSQL code from the command line?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/240513/how-to-pass-variable-to-pl-pgsql-code-from-the-command-line/240542#240542)

Related:

- [Set custom constant in Postgres script](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/321386/set-custom-constant-in-postgres-script/321388#321388)

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Erwin pointed out, you can't declare variables in vanilla PostgreSQL. The way I got around this was by declaring a temp table and inserting the values I needed in there.

```
drop table if exists variables;
create temp table variables (
 timestamp_utc timestamp 
);

insert into variables select current_timestamp;

select timestamp_utc from variables;
drop table if exists variables;
```

It's a lot more code, but it handles the use case I'm working with.

Comment: Put all of that inside a transaction!