# disable autocommit in PostgreSQL 13 on Oracle Linux 8

Tags: postgresql, auto-commit

I know this question has been asked before. I am new to PostgreSQL and would like to turn off "autocommit" forever. After some research, I need to add "\set AUTOCOMMIT off" in the ~/.psqlrc file. Where do I find this file ~/.psqlrc? in directory /var/lib/pgsql/13/data/ I do not find it. I created it "vi ~/.psqlrc" and inserted the command \set AUTOCOMMIT, but it did not work. What is missing here? I would be very happy about any tip.

Many greetings, Ahmed

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include `~/.psqlrc` contents. Use `cat ~/.psqlrc` to print it on the console and copy-paste (do not type, it's easy to make typos) it in to the question.

Comment: as i said, i did not found th file .psqlrc, so i created: [root@~]# vi ~/.psqlrc and add "\set AUTOCOMMIT off" in it. the file contains only this "\set AUTOCOMMIT off". Am i missing somthing?

Comment: It looks correct. You wrote `inserted the command \set AUTOCOMMIT, but...` without the `off` keyword, so just made sure it's there. Anyway, what does `\echo :AUTOCOMMIT` print in a psql session?

Comment: Do not disable autocommit in `psql`. At some point you will forget to close a transaction, and your database may be damaged.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off "autocommit" in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/303155/how-to-turn-off-autocommit-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where do I find this file ~/.psqlrc?

That *already is* the full path to the file.
Linux shells *expand* the "~" character into the path to the current user's Home directory, so something like /home/*username*.
The leading "." in the filename makes it a *hidden* file, so it won't show up in directory listings (ls) unless you include the "-a" flag.  This is a security measure.

However, this is only for the *current user*.
If another user connects through psql, and they don't have this file with this command in it, you're shiny, new setting won't apply to them.
Apparently, making a single psqlrc file for *everyone* is [quite a challenge](https://www.depesz.com/2021/06/23/a-tale-of-making-company-wide-standard-psqlrc/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have created a db-link from Oracle to PostgreSQL and when I insert data via db-link the data is automatically committed, so I want to turn this off. is there a global setting here?

Comment: @AhmedAldam: `psqlrc` only controls the settings for the `psql` tool. It won't affect transactions coming from different tools. You need to check the definition of the DB Link in Oracle.