# Catching exceptions and rolling back transactions

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, transaction, error-handling

I am just trying to see if I understand [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) correctly:

> By default, any error occurring in a PL/pgSQL function aborts
> execution of the function and the surrounding transaction

I have a procedure which does multiple insert operations on different tables, however at the moment I did not make them into a singular transaction. Does the above documentation mean that if an error were to occur all operations performed inside the procedure would be rolled back or do I need to catch exceptions and perform rollback/commit manually?

Comment: "do I need to catch exceptions" -- that depends on how you invoke your procedure.

Comment: I am using supabase and I will either be invoking them using their [api](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/rpc) from client side or periodically using pg_cron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole procedure runs inside a single transaction automatically. Except, if you execute `COMMIT`, which commits everything so far and starts a new transaction.

So, **no**, you do not have to catch exceptions unless you want to. If an exception occurs (and is not caught), the whole transaction is rolled back automatically.

There are some limitations in which constellations a nested `COMMIT` is allowed. Read the manual about [Transaction Management](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-transactions.html).

Be sure to know the difference between *functions* and *procedures* in Postgres:

- [In PostgreSQL, what is the difference between a "Stored Procedure" and other types of functions?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194684/in-postgresql-what-is-the-difference-between-a-stored-procedure-and-other-typ)
- [When to use stored procedure / user-defined function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118418/when-to-use-stored-procedure-user-defined-function/118419#118419)

Comment: Since this in now a Hot Network Question, it should be noted that this does not always apply outside of Postgres. For example, SQL Server's approach to deciding if an error should rollback a transaction is [hilariously unpredictable](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#classification).