# Getting the contents of a json file as a variable in plpgsql?

Tags: postgresql, import, json, plpgsql

I have a function based [this post](http://shuber.io/reading-from-the-filesystem-with-postgres/) by Sean Huber in order to get the content of a file:

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION file_read(file text)     RETURNS void AS $$
> DECLARE
>   content text;
>   tmp text;
> BEGIN
>   file := quote_literal(file);
>   tmp := 'tmp_table';
>
>   EXECUTE 'CREATE TEMP TABLE ' || tmp || ' (content text)';
>   EXECUTE 'COPY ' || tmp || ' FROM ' || file;
>   EXECUTE 'SELECT content FROM ' || tmp INTO content;
>     **Do some more stuff here**
>   EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE ' || tmp;
>
>
> END;   $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
> ```

I'm not really happy with this as it is doing so much more work than necessary. I'd prefer not to create/drop relations cause all I really want to do is run [Postgres' JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) against the content of some .json file. Does anyone know of a better way to do this without using psql?

Comment: Would it be possible to always store the file under the same name on the server? Then you could create an external table through [file_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html) which would "always" be there. Or if you can put them on a webserver (jetty), maybe using the [http extension](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http) would be another alternative

Comment: it wouldn't always be the same name, but the name would be deterministic - the file name will follow a given pattern based on information from the system catalog tables

Comment: Could you concatenate all files into a single (static) one (one line per JSON), with an additional column that identifies the original file name? Then the file_fdw approach might work

Comment: theoretically. But each json file is several megabytes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file contains a valid JSON literal, you *could* read it in with [`pg_read_file()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE) and assign to a `json` variable directly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION file_read(file text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   content json := pg_read_file(file, 0, 10000000);  -- arbitrary max. 10 MB 
BEGIN
   -- do some more stuff here
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**But** that requires superuser privileges for reasons explained in the manual where I linked.

You *could* make that a `SECURITY DEFINER` function, owned by a superuser, but be very careful who to grant the `EXECUTE` privilege then. Example:

- [Creating UUID extension as the non super privileged user](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15535/creating-uuid-extension-as-the-non-super-privileged-user/15539#15539)

Comment: superuser access should be fine. What I'm essentially trying to do is something like Doctor Eval did here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48396608/4781181 where he used \set to make content the cat of a json file but without a psql client